# Defining Courier font in Java Documentation comments

Tags: java, javadoc, enunciate

In my Enunciate API documentation report, I need to change the font of some comment text to "Courier New" font type.

Is is possible?

Comment: For a monospaced font with fixed width letters, `<pre>...</pre>` would do and still is compact.

Comment: `<tt>...</tt>` is slightly more compact and also makes it monospaced. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way for this feature -
Use Font html tag in the comment, Java doc code reads it as a html tag and displays in courier font.

```
/* Sample URL - <font face="courier">https://{Hostname}/programs/FireIn</font>, Replace the host name with the respective environment name</br>
*/
```

Comment: In modern JDK, where HTML5 is used for javadoc - `font` tag is not supported. Javadoc tool shows error `tag not supported in the generated HTML version: font`

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 1.2, Javadoc supports HTML style sheets. You can make these changes to stylesheet.css (located at the root directory of the Javadoc HTML files).

To choose a smaller, sans-serif fonts for the left-hand frames, change this:

```
#FrameItemFont { font-size: normal; font-family: normal }
```

To:

`#FrameItemFont { font-size: 10pt; font-family: helvetica arial sans-serif }`

Customize this yourself for whatever font you want.

Comment: This will allow to change the font across all java doc texts right?? But I would only for specific comment text.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. The CSS defines the format for the entire Javadoc